# The operator ?? what does it mean in flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart

What is the purpose of the ?? operator in Flutter. Could you explain the primary purpose of the ?? operator. how it assist in managing? Additionally, please provide an illustrative example that showcases a practical use case for the ?? operator in a Flutter code.

Comment: Please do web searches before posting to Stack Overflow.

Comment: https://dart.dev/language/operators#conditional-expressions

Comment: Admittedly it's a bit hard to search "??" :) But everyone should have done the dart tour, and it's in there.

Comment: The ?? operator provides null safety in dart which means that if the coming data is null then you can put a default value in it like this (data.item ?? 0) it will return 0 if the data.item is coming null.